# How to seek with DataReader in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, datareader, seek

I load stream into buffer, and consume that with DataReader.

```
private async Task InitializeDataReader()
{
    IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(_file).AsTask();
    _reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
    _reader.UnicodeEncoding = _encoding;
}
```

But sometimes I need to seek `1` byte back from current position. this was actually possible for many readers,

```
_reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);
```

But it doesn't exist for `DataReader`. What is the alternative approach in UWP?

If I shouldn't use DataReader what is the alternative class in `Windows.Storage.Streams`

Comment: Just a quick guess, can you do `_reader.BaseStream.Position--;` ?

Comment: @Laith it doesn't have BaseStream, neither Seek. I think it doesn't support that.

Comment: Maybe try `BinaryReader` instead. It wraps a `Stream` of your choice and it's portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stream and set the stream seek.

Buffer 2 stream:`Stream stream = buffer.AsStream();`

Stream 2 IInputStream:`IInputStream input = stream.AsInputStream();`

DataReader d=new DataReader(input);

You can use stream.Seek to set seek.

Answer (score 0):

For UWP app, `DataReader` clas don't provide such method, as [lindexi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975251/5254458) suggested, the possible way here is using `IRandomAccessStream` interface's [`Seek(UInt64)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream#Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_Seek_System_UInt64_) method

The Seek method supports **random access** to files. Seek allows the read/write position to be moved to any position within the file. This is done with byte offset reference point parameters.

For example:

```
// Create the input stream at position 0 so that the stream can be read 
// from the beginning.
using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
{
        inputStream.Seek(1);//Seeking
        using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
        {
```